# Transform pandas dataframe to dask

Tags: python, pandas, dask, dask-distributed

In the code below I have a `pandas` dataframe that is converted to a `dask` dataframe. Question is: will the process copy the data when it creates the `dask` dataframe, or `dask` will create a wrapper around `pandas` without copying the data? Assume that there are 100 million rows.

```
 import pandas
 import dask.dataframe as daskDataFrame

 IDs = [1,2,3 ......]
 lastNames = ['Smith', 'Williams', 'Jackson' ......]
 pandasDataFrame = pandas.DataFrame({'Person ID':IDs, 'Last Name': lastNames},
        columns=['Person ID', 'Last Name']) 

 daskDataFrame = daskDataFrame.from_pandas(pandasDataFrame, npartitions=100)
```

Comment: Why not directly reading with dask instead of reading in pandas and transform it to dask dataframe?

Comment: Because the input is generated by another process

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dask will create a task graph that references the `pandas` dataframe, see the [source code](https://github.com/dask/dask/blob/ff63ae7e5f5c8ae724d1347cf19732ebe6675d52/dask/dataframe/io/io.py#L134-L234), specifically:

```py
  dsk = {
        (name, i): data.iloc[start:stop]
        for i, (start, stop) in enumerate(zip(locations[:-1], locations[1:]))
    }
```

Comment: What about the partitions? How is that handled without a copy?

Comment: Partitions are `delayed` objects, so it's just a reference to specific objects/functions. If your concern is memory, one option is to write the pandas dataframe to disk, delete the pandas object in memory and load the data from disk with dask.